# How to count number of visits in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a new column in my datatable in R studio that categorizes my data by "visits".

Here is an example data table:

```
library(data.table)
reprex_1 = data.table(
  `Receiver Number`=c("Receiver A", "Receiver B", "Receiver B","Receiver B","Receiver B", "Receiver B", "Receiver B","Receiver C", "Receiver C", "Receiver C"),
  Transmitter = c("Tag 1", "Tag 2" , "Tag 3" , "Tag 3",  "Tag 3" , "Tag 3" , "Tag 3","Tag 4" ,"Tag 4",  "Tag 4"),
  `Station Name` = c("Station A","Station B","Station B","Station B","Station B", "Station B","Station B","Station C","Station C","Station C"),
  TimeDiff = c( NA,NA,NA,221536,1114, 425,10728,110131,61,43)
)
Receiver Number  Transmitter Station Name TimeDiff
Receiver A       Tag 1       Station A       NA
Receiver B       Tag 2       Station B       NA
Receiver B       Tag 3       Station B       NA
Receiver B       Tag 3       Station B   221536
Receiver B       Tag 3       Station B     1114
Receiver B       Tag 3       Station B      425
Receiver B       Tag 3       Station B    10728
Receiver C       Tag 4       Station C   110131
Receiver C       Tag 4       Station C       61
Receiver C       Tag 4       Station C       43
```

I need to create a new column of visits, where each visit is grouped by Receiver Number, Transmitter, Station Name, and TimeDiff <1800. Each visit will be a unique combination of the first three columns and rows within those combinations that have a TimeDiff >1800 or *NA* also form a new visit. I would like this in consecutive numbering (1,2,3...)

Here is what I would like:

```
Receiver Number Transmitter Station Name TimeDiff Visit
Receiver A       Tag 1      Station A       NA     1
Receiver B       Tag 2      Station B       NA     2
Receiver B       Tag 3      Station B       NA     3
Receiver B       Tag 3      Station B   221536     4
Receiver B       Tag 3      Station B     1114     4
Receiver B       Tag 3      Station B      425     4
Receiver B       Tag 3      Station B    10728     5
Receiver C       Tag 4      Station C   110131     6
Receiver C       Tag 4      Station C       61     6
Receiver C       Tag 4      Station C       43     6
```

I have looked at other examples of categorizing rows by based on grouped data and can get R to create visits based on the unique combinations of the first three columns (Receiver Number, Transmitter, and Station Name), but I can't figure out how to include the condition of TimeDiff >1800 to also enabling a new visit.

This is what I can get to, but doesn't include creating new visits by TimedDiff >1800:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(reprex_1)[,AttemptVisit:=.GRP, by = c("Receiver Number","Station Name", "Transmitter")]

Receiver Number Transmitter Station Name TimeDiff AttemptVisit
Receiver A       Tag 1    Station A       NA            1
Receiver B       Tag 2    Station B       NA            2
Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B       NA            3
Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B   221536            3
Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B     1114            3
Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B      425            3
Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B    10728            3
Receiver C       Tag 4    Station C   110131            4
Receiver C       Tag 4    Station C       61            4
Receiver C       Tag 4    Station C       43            4
```

I would appreciate any help you could provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. We use a `cumsum` of the `NA` or >1800 values as part of the grouper:

```
reprex_1[, visit := .GRP,
         by = .(`Receiver Number`, Transmitter, `Station Name`, cumsum(TimeDiff > 1800 | is.na(TimeDiff)))]
# reprex_1
#     Receiver Number Transmitter Station Name TimeDiff visit
#  1:      Receiver A       Tag 1    Station A       NA     1
#  2:      Receiver B       Tag 2    Station B       NA     2
#  3:      Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B       NA     3
#  4:      Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B   221536     4
#  5:      Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B     1114     4
#  6:      Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B      425     4
#  7:      Receiver B       Tag 3    Station B    10728     5
#  8:      Receiver C       Tag 4    Station C   110131     6
#  9:      Receiver C       Tag 4    Station C       61     6
# 10:      Receiver C       Tag 4    Station C       43     6
```

Comment: another option is `reprex_1[, visit := rleid(`Receiver Number`, Transmitter, `Station Name`, cumsum(TimeDiff > 1800 | is.na(TimeDiff)))]`